# Rescaling and wrong colors after using transform:scale on hover

Tags: html, css

I have an image with a div inside a block that scales bigger on mouse hover and then the block becomes the display block on hover. The code I have is likes this:

```
<div>
  <img>
  <div class="social-sharing">
    <a href="#" class="fb">Fb</a>
    <a href="#" class="twitter">Twitter</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

My CSS (LESS) is like the following:

```
div {
  &:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    .social-sharing {
      display: block;
    }
  }
  .social-sharing {
    display: none;
    .fb {
      border-right: 3px solid #fff;
    }
  }
}
```

When I hover the img re-scales a little bit, what is even more important to me is the white of the border isn't just white it is gray.

You can see it [in my codepen](http://codepen.io/Sukrams/pen/RGNkEW)

Why is it like this and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I do not realy understand your problem, but I'll try...

If you wanna have a complete white border around your Facebook-Button, just write `border: 3px solid #fff;`, instead of `border-right: 3px solid #fff;`

If you wanna have a complete white border arround just put the `border 3x solid #fff` directly into the `.social-sharing`-Block.

You'll find some more information how to use the `border`-Functions in CSS for example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp).

Comment: When i hover over the img/div, the border isn't just white, as it should be, it's even more something like a gray tone. Thats my problem.

Comment: @Sukrams sorry, but the border _is_ on my screen white. Maybe it is a problem with your computer-screen or the rest of your CSS on your webpage.

Comment: strange thing... now it works fine, here too, but yesterday not. Maybe temporary browser issues oder something like that